# Termux permission denied

Tags: android, c++, termux

I want to execute a simple code in Termux(c++) but every time I get an error:

```
bash: ./test.cpp: Permission denied
Storage permission is on and gcc is installed.
```

Do I need root or something else?

Comment: You can't execute a C++ source file, you need to compile and link it first to create an executable file. Instructions should be there in any introduction to C++.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue `ls -l test.sh; ./test.sh` gives `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Nov 14 12:35 test sh
bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As molbdnilo said, you should compile your source file first :

```
g++ test.cpp
```

And then execute the binary produced (the default name is a.out)

```
./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile and run it in termux's own directory.
Just start termux:

```
cd storage/ 
nano test.cpp
g++ test.cpp "./a.out"
```

You can run it!

Answer (score 0):

C++ can't do it,you must compile first.
And if it Python,you can add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to first line,and in shell run `chmod 744 xxx.py`,and then run `./xxx.py`.xxx.py is running.

Answer (score -1):

I never used termux but would Like to suggest U following points for compiling

- use `chmod 777 test.cpp` to grant the permission for read write and execute to all users
- use g++ along with gcc to compile C++ files
  use `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install g++`
- compile using `g++ test.cpp -o test`
  and use `./test` to execute the file.
  This is how it work in Linux systems.

Comment: Setting the executable bits on a source file is not a good idea.